# Add column of row count in the table

Tags: oracle

I have received a table like this after my sql query

```
  LOT_NO         x

A-TJ26-03-1-030  2
A-TJ26-03-1-020  1
A-TJ26-03-1-040  3
```

I want to add a third column in this table with value of total number of row in it like this:

```
  LOT_NO         x  Count

A-TJ26-03-1-030  2    3
A-TJ26-03-1-020  1    3
A-TJ26-03-1-040  3    3
```

I am able to get count value of this table but as i want compare x-column and count-column using logic in java, so i want to create one new column with row count in this table.
How can i do this. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Which data base are you using Oracle orMysql

Comment: oracle database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `count(*) over()` to get total count. Here is the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/408035/2).

```
select
    LOT_NO,
    x,
    count(*) over () as count
from yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below syntax of alter statement to add new column,

```
alter table table_name add column_name data_type;
```

Eg:

```
alter table table_name add count number(38,0)
```